# If you use Google as a sign in provider in Firebase, will there always be an email associated with that user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

For example, obviously if you use email as a provider there will be an email associated, and if you use Twitter that is not the case. I was wondering if you can always get an email address if they log in using Google as the sign in provider. I haven't seen a case without an email but I would like to verify that this is always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounts from the Google sign-in provider will indeed always have an email address associated with them.

In fact, as far as I know, the email address for this provider is also always already verified by the provider.

---

**Edit**: I just realized that it may be possible to change the scopes that you request, in which case you *can* exclude the email address from the requested scopes and not get an email address. I've never done this myself, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Is there any documentation about which providers will always have email?